# Modified value of variable in debugging is not kept after a step

Tags: pydev

I tried to debug a python script in Eclipse and I changed the value for a variable and after a step in the value was not kept.

Why the new value is not kept? 
This is a bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends a lot on the use case -- because of some Python shortcomings, it's expected that it doesn't work in some scenarios.

Now, to determine if that's the case for your particular use case, you need to provide more information, such as the actual code, Python version and PyDev version.

Comment: I used pydev 6.2 and python 2.7. The code is the following :                              
`a=3 
b=4
c=a+b

print a
print b
print c ` And I tried to change the value of the variable but after I did a step is kept the old value not the new value.

Comment: Creating a snippet with that and changing the value of `a` does work for me... probably needs more info to be able to replicate it here.

Comment: I tried to change the value of `a` from Debug perspective-> Variable view right click on `a` and select Change Value I typed 5 and and in the console was displayed this message _Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "…/org.python.pydev_6.2.0/pysrc/_pydevd_bundle/pydevd_vars.py", line 387, in change_attr_expression value = eval(expression, frame.f_globals, frame.f_locals) File "<string>", line 1 int: 5  ^ SyntaxError: invalid syntax _ . In the Varibles view I can see the new value but If I want to print in console the value of `a` is still 3 and after a step `a` have the old value

Comment: It seems the expression you're putting is not valid... the new value must be a valid expression (if you post a screenshot showing the expression you're typing I can help say what you should put -- putting just `5` does work for me).

Comment: I succeeded to change the value of `a` I must to type just "5" not "int: 5". But If I have a big structure how can I modify just a part of it ?

Comment: To modify just a part of a structure I recommend using the python console to access it and change it as needed (you can use the console to print and change things as needed).

Comment: Thank you for your help